# How do I apply a function to each connected components within a graph/network?

Tags: r, graph, social-networking, igraph

I have a large igraph object 70,000+ vertices (nodes) and 200,000+ edges (connections).  I'd like to calculate some measures of centrality but the network is too big.  I thought a good work around would be to break my network into connected components (even the largest isn't too big).

I was thinking about using the igraph function [clusters](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc/R/clusters.html) or related methods.  Could I then calculate alpha.centrality() and bonpow() on the clusters? and then merge the results back into the original igraph object? (or a dataframe with all vertices)

I'm not sure of the best approach and I'd be really interested to hear any ideas people have.  Many thanks :)

Comment: Without a full understanding of your structure it's hard to say, but if each node was an element in a list() you could use llply() and walk away from the computer for a bit :)

Comment: @Brandon do you mean that each _italic_connected component_italic_ is an element in a list?  Since the functions I'm referring to need to be computed on the largest connected component that each node is a part of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `decompose.graph` function in igraph to obtain a list of the connected components, then use `lapply` to run your function (`alpha.centrality` or `bonpow`) on each of the components. After having run `decompose.graph`, you may want to deallocate your original graph to re-claim some memory.

Comment: @Michael Might want to consider using parLapply from the SNOW package to speed things up if you have some spare cores on your machine or access to a machine with several cores.